# Is there a continously differentiable function which is 2nd order differentiable only at origin？

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

What about higher dimensions？I first thought about x times characteristic functions of rational numbers but it is not in C1 class.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be a continuous, nowhere differentiable function on $\mathbb R.$ Define $f(x) = \int _0^x t^2 g(t)\, dt.$ Then by the FTC, $f'(x) = x^2g(x)$ for all $x.$ Thus $f \in C^1(\mathbb R).$ Verify that $f''(0)= 0,$ but that $f''(x)$ fails to exist for $x\ne 0.$